# How to handle navigation back button event in xamarin iOS/Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, navigation, back-button

I am creating xamarin form app and I want to perform some action on navigation back button.Is there any approach to do that?

P.S :> Software back button, not Hardware back button.

Answer (score 3):

In [this article](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/), you'll find everything.

IF the article disappears or changes at some point, here you will find the specifics of the solution.

**You'll need to create a Custom ContentPage**

```
namespace WhateverYourNamespace
    {
        public class CoolContentPage : ContentPage
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or Sets the Back button click overriden custom action
            /// </summary>
            public Action CustomBackButtonAction { get; set; }

            public static readonly BindableProperty EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty =
                   BindableProperty.Create(
                   nameof(EnableBackButtonOverride),
                   typeof(bool),
                   typeof(CoolContentPage),
                   false);

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or Sets Custom Back button overriding state
            /// </summary>
            public bool EnableBackButtonOverride
            {
                get
                {
                    return (bool)GetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty);
                }
                set
                {
                    SetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you see, there's an action event that we are going to subscribe to in our Xamarin Forms code level and to be invoked from Xamarin native project level.

There is also a bool property to enable or disable the overriding of the Back Button click event so that you can decide whether to subscribe to the overriding event or not as a page property.

**Android** :
You'll need to override the OnOptionsItemSelected() event in our MainActivity class in order to capture the nav bar back button click in Android for Xamarin Forms.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        // check if the current item id 
        // is equals to the back button id
        if (item.ItemId == 16908332)
        {
           // retrieve the current xamarin forms page instance
           var currentpage = (CoolContentPage)
           Xamarin.Forms.Application.
           Current.MainPage.Navigation.
           NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

           // check if the page has subscribed to 
           // the custom back button event
           if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
           {
             // invoke the Custom back button action
             currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
             // and disable the default back button action
             return false;
           }

           // if its not subscribed then go ahead 
           // with the default back button action
           return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        else
        {
           // since its not the back button 
           //click, pass the event to the base
           return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        // this is not necessary, but in Android user 
        // has both Nav bar back button and
        // physical back button its safe 
        // to cover the both events

        // retrieve the current xamarin forms page instance
        var currentpage = (CoolContentPage)
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.
        Current.MainPage.Navigation.
        NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

        // check if the page has subscribed to 
        // the custom back button event
        if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
        {
            currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**iOS :**
 iOS you need to override the ViewWillAppear() method in your CoolContentPageRenderer class.

So the below code should be placed inside your CoolContentPageRenderer class.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
     base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

     if (((CoolContentPage)Element).EnableBackButtonOverride)
     {
          SetCustomBackButton();
     }
}

private void SetCustomBackButton()
{
     // Load the Back arrow Image
     var backBtnImage = 
     UIImage.FromBundle("iosbackarrow.png");

     backBtnImage = 
     backBtnImage.ImageWithRenderingMode
     (UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);

     // Create our Button and set Edge 
     // Insets for Title and Image
     var backBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom)
     {
          HorizontalAlignment =   
          UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left,
          TitleEdgeInsets = 
          new UIEdgeInsets(11.5f, 15f, 10f, 0f),
          ImageEdgeInsets = 
          new UIEdgeInsets(1f, 8f, 0f, 0f)
     };

     // Set the styling for Title
     // You could set any Text as you wish here
     backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
     // use the white color in ios back button text
     backBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White,
     UIControlState.Normal); 
     backBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.LightGray, 
     UIControlState.Highlighted);
     backBtn.Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue",
     (nfloat)17);

     // Set the Image to the button
     backBtn.SetImage(backBtnImage, UIControlState.Normal);

     // Allow the button to Size itself
     backBtn.SizeToFit();

     // Add the Custom Click event you would like to 
     // execute upon the Back button click
     backBtn.TouchDown += (sender, e) =>
     {
          // Whatever your custom back button click handling
          if(((CoolContentPage)Element)?.
          CustomBackButtonAction != null)
          {    
            ((CoolContentPage)Element)?.
               CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
          }
     };

     //Set the frame of the button
     backBtn.Frame = new CGRect(
          0,
          0,
          UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 4,
          NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height);

     // Add our button to a container
     var btnContainer = new UIView(
     new CGRect(0, 0, 
     backBtn.Frame.Width, backBtn.Frame.Height));
     btnContainer.AddSubview(backBtn);

     // A dummy button item to push our custom  back button to
     // the edge of screen (sort of a hack)
     var fixedSpace = 
     new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace)
     {
          Width = -16f
     };
     // wrap our custom back button with a UIBarButtonItem
     var backButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("",
     UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null)
     {
          CustomView = backBtn
     };

     // Add it to the ViewController
     NavigationController.TopViewController.
     NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems 
     = new[] { fixedSpace, backButtonItem };
}
```

**How to use it** :

```
<WhateverYourNamespace:CoolContentPage 
 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 xmlns:WhateverYourNamespace=
 "clrnamespace:XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride;
 assembly=XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride"
 x:Class="XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride.Page2"             
 Title="Page 3"
 EnableBackButtonOverride="True"
 BackgroundColor="#00bfff">
  <StackLayout
    Spacing="20"
    Padding="20,10,20,10"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" >

    <Label Text="This is the cool page, 
    which has the Navigation Bar Back button 
    click overriden. How go ahead and click that Back     
        button! ;)"
           FontSize="20"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           TextColor="White"/>

  </StackLayout>
</WhateverYourNamespace:CoolContentPage>
```

Comment: While this link might hold the answer to this question, it might disappear or change at some point in time. Please add the specifics of the solution in this link to your answer here.

Comment: @FrqSalah I have already done this but I am facing error and I have also mentioned my error on that post.

Comment: @BhautikDalicha what are the errors you're facing? Please explain everything in your question

Comment: @FrqSalah After doing all this still, it intercepts only hardware back button.

Answer (score 0):

For ANDROID add this in you main activity OnCreate() after LoadApplication(new App()) line.

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar 
    = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarSetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: What about iOS?